# Configuring IIS 7.5 to enable server side includes (SSI) for the '.html' extension

Tags: html, windows, iis, iis-7.5, ssi

I want to configure **Server Side Includes (SSI)** in IIS 7.5. By default, the file extension that indicates that a file should be processed as an SSI file is **.shtml**. However, I want to configure IIS so that files with the ***.html*** extension are processed as SSI files. This is to enable me to change the footer for multiple **.html** pages by changing a single file named **footer.html**.

Is this possible, and if so, are there are any caveats?

I would also be receptive to suggestions for **alternative** approaches to changing the footer on multiple HTML pages by changing just a single file.

Comment: **Related:** [Use web.config to allow server-side includes in HTML files (IIS)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17688185/1497596)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey got the answer just needed to surf some more 
Here is the link where you can configure IIS server to use Server side include for .html pages as its default provided for .shtml but I didnt wanted that. this link is very helpful

http://tech.mikeal.com/blog1.php/server-side-includes-for-html-in-iis7

Comment: Unfortunately, the provided link is no longer available. This is why link-only answers can be problematic.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something likes below.

**CONFIGURATION SAMPLE**

The following configuration sample disables the #exec command for SSI files in the Default Web Site.

```
<location path="Default Web Site">
   <system.webServer>
      <serverSideInclude ssiExecDisable="true" />
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

**C# file looks like below**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample
{
   private static void Main()
   {
      using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
      {
         Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

         ConfigurationSection serverSideIncludeSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/serverSideInclude", "Default Web Site");
         serverSideIncludeSection["ssiExecDisable"] = true;

         serverManager.CommitChanges();
      }
   }
}
```

You can get more information [**Server Side Include**](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/serversideinclude)

**For your 2nd Question:**

You can use **Master page**.Then all inherited pages will have both headers and Footers.

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thanks Sampath bhai i also found one solution.