# Use web.config to allow server-side includes in HTML files (IIS)

Tags: html, iis, iis-7.5, ssi, server-side-includes

In IIS 7.5, is it possible to use **web.config** alone to enable **SSI** processing for files that have the **.html** extension? Specifically, I don't want to use the default SSI extension, **.shtml**.

**Reason:** I don't want to change the extensions. Doing so would lead to broken links in search engine results.

Also, my motivation for doing this in **web.config** is because this is a **shared server**.

Comment: Related: [Configuring IIS 7.5 to enable server side includes (SSI) for the '.html' extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14135582/1497596)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presuming that your hoster has enabled SSI's *and* delegated Read/Write permissions for handler mappings then this should work:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="SSINC-html" 
                 path="*.html" 
                 verb="*" 
                 modules="ServerSideIncludeModule" 
                 resourceType="File" 
                 requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Whilst we're on the topic, Robert McMurray (MSFT IIS staffer) has a fairly recent refresher blog post all about SSI's here:

> http://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/archive/2010/12/28/iis-notes-on-server-side-includes-ssi-syntax-kb-203064-revisited.aspx

Comment: Great link! I'd been looking for something like that blog post.

Comment: An [alternative link on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2010/12/28/iis-notes-on-server-side-includes-ssi-syntax-kb-203064-revisited.aspx) to the same article.